# Wrong copy of folder in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I try to copy my `build` folder to `/usr/share/nginx/html`
So I want to have as result:

```
/usr/share/nginx/html/build/xxx
```

I perform this inside my dockerfile

```
cp -r  build /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

But then than all the content of my `build/` folder is copied inside `/usr/share/nginx/html` and not the folder itself
So like: `/usr/share/nginx/html/xxx`

When I perform the exactly same command inside my running container it happens in the right way!?
Than I got `/usr/share/nginx/html/build/xxx`
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: why do you need copy it, could you use `-v /usr/share/nginx/html/build:/usr/share/nginx/html` with `docker run` command???

Comment: Shouldn't you be using docker COPY and ADD?

Comment: This is some test image where we perform our npm install inside our image and than copy the created build folder to our nginx folder (not the best approacht but we wanted some very easy way to show everyone the UI)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how exactly the Docker daemon works during image building but according to the documentation for `COPY` there is a clause that says;

> **COPY**
>   If  is a directory, the entire contents of the directory are
>   copied, including filesystem metadata. Note: The directory itself is
>   not copied, just its contents.

Obviously we are talking about the Linux `cp` command and not docker's `COPY` but it sounds like the rule somehow seems to have been applied to `cp` as well?

**See:**
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#/copy

For fixing your problem - probably just use the `ADD` command to copy your `build` directory?

**Example:** (Assuming your `build` directory is at the same level as `Dockerfile`;

`ADD build /usr/share/nginx/html/`

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Hi Toh, I don't try to COPY the build folder in my image (it's not in the directory with my dockerfile etc.) The Dockerfile performs an npm install and that creates a build directory (which is in my image already) and than I try to copy my build folder (which is already in my image) to another path

Comment: I sort of got what you meant but please correct me if I am wrong. If you are looking at making sure that the nginx html path has a build directory in it, with all the files (in build) created after npm install, then why not `mkdir /usr/share/nginx/html/build`? So `npm install && mkdir /usr/share/nginx/html/build && cp -r build /usr/share/nginx/html/build/`